# Inverse Radon Transform in Python

Tags: python, transform, scikit-image

I am trying to build a code in Python that does image processing, but I am stuck in a part where I have to do an Inverse Radon Transform. I am using the standard iradon() function in Python.

When I try to execute it, the function returns me "The given `theta` does not match the number of projections in `radon_image`." According to this, I should pass the function an array of angles equal to the image size. This makes no sense since I might have less angles than the size of the image (i.e. 180 angles and the image is 256*256)

So I have a matrix of angles (21x28) and I get 21 SUBSETS. While I iterate the subsets (2nd axis of angles) I need to perform the inverse Radon transform for a specific image, based on the angles[i].

Since the angles array is only 21 elements, and the image is 256px it throws the error.

Anyone has any idea or direction how should I proceed?

Thanks in advance

I want to run an Inverse Radon Transform and I have an image, and an array of angles (which is split in mini arrays).

I expect to run the function iradon() normally.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Each column of the image is a projection, so if the image is NxM, ideally you want >= M reconstruction angles for accurate reconstruction